# Syntax Error when using range in if function in Acrobat Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I'm trying to get a text field to disappear based on a previously calculated number with Javascript for Adobe Acrobat. I want the text field to disappear only if the number in the previous field is equal to, or greater than 0, or less than 75.

I have no problems getting it to function if I only use less than 75, but when I try to introduce the range it fails.

I'm using Custom calculation script in the field that changes visibility.

This script works:

```
if (this.getField("PreviouslyCalculatedField").value < 75) {
    event.target.display = display.hidden;
} else {
    event.target.display = display.visible;
    this.getField("FieldToChangeVisibility").value = "Hello world."
}
```

This is the script that fails:

```
if (this.getField("PreviouslyCalculatedField").value >= 0 && < 75) {
    event.target.display = display.hidden;
} else {
    event.target.display = display.visible;
    this.getField("FieldToChangeVisibility").value = "Hello world."
}
```

It produces "Syntax Error: Invalid XML name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat JavaScript does not have an operator to combine limits in one `if` statement.

You would use this statement:

```
if (this.getField("PreviouslyCalculatedField").value >= 0 && this.getField("PreviouslyCalculatedField").value < 75) {
```

and then it would work.